# i need to run php5 ./server.php command on ec2 instance without keeping my system on all the time?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, websocket, command-line-interface

i need to run php5 ./server.php command on ec2 instance to support websocket. and i dont't want to keep my system on all the time . So how can i run it in background or any better direction you can point ??

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to keep it on all the time then you can use cronjob to specify when do you want it to run and when to stop.

To access your cronjob, use `crontab -e`.

Read more about `cronjob` at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto